# Using Morph in Powerpoint to rotate an object more than 360 degrees

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation with a SmartArt element showing an 8-stage cycle. In the first slide the entire SmartArt graphic is centred in the slide to show the whole thing, and it moves largely off the slide for the following slides to highlight individual stages of the cycle. I have object-level Morph transitions between a series of slides, and ideally I'd like to spin the SmartArt graphic multiple revolutions in the transition to the next slide.

I've tried setting the graphic's rotation attribute in the second slide to 3600°, but it doesn't seem to take that into account.

Anyone got any idea on how to make that rotation happen? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Morph, try giving the shape a Spin animation and set it Effect Options to two full spins and have it start With Previous.

You can set the rotation speed by changing the duration setting.

In use, it looks like it's doing more than two full spins.

Comment: I'll give it a go and see if I can make it spin while moving, then I'll update here. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Alas, no; it waited until the slide transition (and thus the move from center to the corner) was complete, then spun on the spot. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: You might need to do something like creating a movie or animated GIF of a spinning shape, then inserting that into PPT and animating it to produce the move.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the case. Cheers - it was worth a try. :)